# Give '%' on Bar Chart Datalabel Chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am working with `chartjs` and I am wondering how to give '%' on datalabel of bar chart. My code like below:

```
data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'My Label',
        data: <?php echo json_encode($myData); ?> // contains number like: 77.43, 78.22, etc
        datalabels: {
            align: 'end',
            anchor: 'end'
        }
    }],

    labels: <?php echo json_encode($myLabel); ?>
}
```

I tried to put string '%' like this `data: <?php echo json_encode($myData); ?> + '%'` but it returned nothing but a blank page. So anyone can help me to fix this?

Comment: Data given to Chart is supposed to be something like this `data: [20, 10]` OR `data: [{x:'2016-12-25', y:20}, {x:'2016-12-26', y:10}]`. You're trying to add `%` which maybe causing the chart to break.

Comment: I see, so do you have any solutions to make each value has '%'?

Comment: I don't see any such `options` in the official docs of `chart.js` to add a `label`  with `value %`. they just seem to support `legends`

Comment: Yeah, I've searched in their docs, thats why I come here with this question. Legends and tooltips are quite helpful choices for now

Comment: Maybe try some other charting `scripts` if that label `value %` is of importance on your UI.

Comment: Yes you right @RohitBatra

Comment: @RohitBatra I found the answer, check my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can setting the `tooltip` in the following way:

```
data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'My Label',
        data: <?php echo json_encode($myData); ?> // contains number like: 77.43, 78.22, etc
        datalabels: {
            align: 'end',
            anchor: 'end'
        }
    }],

    labels: <?php echo json_encode($myLabel); ?>
},
options: {            
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label +': ' + tooltipItems.yLabel + ' %';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference : http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

Comment: tooltip is not the solution I want sir, I just want it appear on datalabel. But it will be a quite helpful choice tho

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the solution on `Chartjs` Official Github Page. I just need to put

```
formatter: function (value) {
    return value + "%";
}
```

inside `datalabels`

It acts similar with `callback` in `yAxes` option.

See [this link](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/issues/39)

Answer (score -1):

add quotes around php code and end with a comma:  `data: "<?...?>",`

Comment: I have tried that one actually, but it returned a blank page